# Populating ListBox in wix installer

Tags: listbox, wix, windows-installer, installation, listitem

I have created a ListBox in my wix project and i want to populate that ListBox with values coming from the custom action. What i want is that on click of a button my custom action should get called and further my ListBox should get populated. I don't know what is going wrong. So, if anyone knows how to do it, please help. Thanx in advance.

Code in My Custom Action:-

```
Database db = session.Database;
string var = db.Tables["ListBox"].SqlInsertString + "TEMPORARY";
Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.View var2 = db.OpenView(var);
var2.Execute(new Record(new object[] {"PROPERTY NAME", 5, "5", "value"}));
var2.Close();
```

Code in Wix project:-

```
<Control Id="ANY ID" Property="PROPERTY NAME" Type="ListBox" X="20" Y="20" Width="300" Height="300" Sorted="yes">
<ListBox Property="PROPERTY NAME">
    <ListItem Text="[PROPERTY NAME]" Value="[PROPERTY NAME]"/>
</ListBox>
</Control>
```

Code on Button for Calling Custom Action and refreshing value of property that is set on ListBox:-

```
<Control Id="ANY ID" Type="PushButton" Text="[Next]" Height="200" Width="200" X="160" Y="160" Bitmap="yes" FixedSize="yes" Default="yes">
<Publish Event="DoAction" Value="CustomAction">1</Publish>
<Publish Property="PROPERTY NAME" Value="[PROPERTY NAME]" Order="2">2</Publish>
</Control>
```

After all this, I am not able to see the value that is being inserted to the table  in CustomAction or in other words, the ListBox is not getting populated after doing all this.

Answer (score 2):

It will not work this way.
We have to call the Custom Action On load of the next dialog.
This works for me:-

```
<InstallUISequence>
<Custom Action="NAME_OF_CUSTOM_ACTION" Before="DIALOG_NAME_ON_WHICH_YOU_WANT_TO POPULATE_THE_LISTBOX"/>
<Show Dialog="DIALOG_NAME_ON_WHICH_YOU_WANT_TO POPULATE_THE_LISTBOX"
After="PREVIOUS_DIALOG_NAME"/>
</InstallUISequence>
```